# How do I change the default location for mule application log files?

Tags: mule

I would like to change the log directory from **MULE_HOME/logs** to **MULE_HOME/logs/apps**.  The only place I have found that refers to a file path is in **MULE_HOME/conf/wrapper.conf**.  Editing the **wrapper.logfile** does allow me to relocate the mule_ee.log file, which seems to be the Mule application log, but I'd like to include Mule application logs there, too.  If I create an application called FOO and deploy it to the runtime environment, it will create a file called **MULE_HOME/logs/mule-app-FOO.log**, but changing the location seems to be difficult short of completely messing things up writing custom log4j2 XML files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Mule version 3.6+, then it is recommended to use **log4j2.xml** instead of **log4j.xml**.... Using log4j2 you can change the path and get your application log ... a simple example would be :-

```
 <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${env:MULE_HOME}/logs/${sys:CustomapplicationName}.log"
filePattern="${env:MULE_HOME}/logs/${sys:CustomapplicationName}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log"> <!-- CustomapplicationName is set at mule-app.properties or in VM argument in Run As Configure as -DCustomapplicationName=Log4j -->
<PatternLayout>
<pattern>%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}- %c{1}: %m%n</pattern>
</PatternLayout>
<Policies>
<SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="120 KB" />
</Policies>
<DefaultRolloverStrategy max="1" />
</RollingFile>
```

Just put this above code in your log4j2.xml in `src/main/resource` folder
Here in above  you can see that, you have configured your path of your log files by mentioning here:-

```
<RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${env:MULE_HOME}/logs/apps/${sys:CustomapplicationName}.log"
    filePattern="${env:MULE_HOME}/logs/apps/${sys:CustomapplicationName}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
```

where `${sys:CustomapplicationName}` is the System variable set in mule-app.properties as following :-

```
CustomapplicationName=yourApplicationName
```

Comment: Providing an example was very helpful to me.  Simple answers like, fix it in log4j2.xml, while correction, doesn't really move very far towards a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Right way is to have log4j properties / xml file for FOO application and have that define the desired path for FOO application log. This way will ensure mule_ee.log is not messed up and at the same time other applications too will have their own log files which will be easy to manage and easy to introspect specific application log in case of errors / exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Define location in log4j.properties file.